# Windows XP SP3 does not want to connect to the Web

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp

ALL,

I have a very old Dell laptop which has Windows XP on it.

I also run a LAN here at home and all my machines are connected to the Web except this one.

I do have a proper IP when I do ipconfig: 192.168.1.43, however trying to ping either 8.8.8.8 or google.com results in the 100% packets loss.

Trying to run IE I received an error page "Internet Explorer cannot display this page". Trying to click on the "Diagnose Connection Problem" I will receive "Windows does not manage your wireless network".

I found [this](https://www.nashvillecomputerguru.com/knowledge-base-faq/troubleshooting-wireless-networks/how-to-configure-windows-xp-to-manage-wireless-network-connections/), but I can't perform the operations described there because on "Wireless Network Connection Properties" dialog I don;t have "Wireless Properties" tab. I instead have "Advanced" tab which does not have such a ckecbox at all.

So what can I do? How can I make Windows XP laptop have a connection?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

```
ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name.......................: fordanworkxp
Primary DNS Suffix..............:
Node Type.......................: Broadcast
IP Routing Enabled..............: No
WING Proxy Enabled..............: No
DNS Suffix Search List..........: bcld.al.comcast.net

Ethernet Adapter Local Area Connection 2:

Media State.....................: Media Disconnected
Description.....................: Broadcom 440x 10/100 Integrated Controller
Physical Address................: 00-15-C5-BB-71-67

Ethernet Adapter Wireless Network Connection

Connection-specific DNS Suffix.: hcdl.al.comcast.net
Description....................: Dell Wireless 1790 Wireless Mini-Card
Physical Address...............: 00-16-CF-0C-09-03
Dhcp Enabled...................: Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled......: Yes
IP Address.....................: 192.168.1.43
Subnet Mask....................: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway................: 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server....................: 192.168.1.1
DNS Servers....................: 75.75.75.75
                                 75.75.75.75
Lease Obtained.................: Thursday August 27, 2009 12:33:50 AM
Lease Expires..................: Thursday September 01 2009 12:33:50 AM
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: Please provide the complete output of `ipconfig /all`. Additionally, are there any anti-virus or security programs on the computer?

Comment: @Appleoddity, please see the edit of the OP. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The lease date on that IP address if from 2009. Not likely it is valid. The question is why hasn’t the computer renewed its IP address?

Let’s run the following commands from a `cmd` prompt:

```
ipconfig /release
netsh int ip reset reset.txt
netsh winsock reset
netsh firewall reset
```

Reboot your computer and see if the internet works now.

The above commands will reset your IP stack to default.

Just a little disclaimer. Windows XP is an end of life operating system that no longer receives important security updates from Microsoft. Putting Windows XP on the internet is a highly risky choice.

Comment: I did just that and rebooted. Nothing changed. pinging still fails. Also, I do know that XP is expired. But I have a software installed on this system which I don't have a disk anymore. And so need to keep this system for a while... I even tried to set a `date` and then do `ipconfig /release`/`ipconfig /renew`. Still no change - ping 8.8.8.8 fails...

Comment: also trying to ping 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.1 works, so the card works and it sends everything out to the router. But there everything is lost.